# How can I import data from my database into my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a PHP Graph that I copied from [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/dynamic-live-multi-series-chart/) and I have been trying to find a way to get some values from my **Data Base (which is constantly being updated)** into the Graph. I have successfully been able to import the values that were already on the Data Base but I can't seem to find a way to get the new values to the function updateChart().

I have been trying to find a solution for a long time and haven't found anything would work, I tried to look into a way using $.GET but it doesn't seem to have worked

```
function updateChart() {

var deltaY1, deltaY2;
xValue += updateInterval;
// adding random value
yValue1 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));
yValue2 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));

// pushing the new values
dataPoints1.push({
    x: xValue,
    y: yValue1
});
dataPoints2.push({
    x: xValue,
    y: yValue2
});

// updating legend text with  updated with y Value 
chart.options.data[0].legendText = "Building A " + yValue1 + " watts";
chart.options.data[1].legendText = " Building B " + yValue2+ " watts"; 
chart.render();}
```

I am unsure on how to proceed with something like this and since most tutorials online talk only about very basic stuff.

I would gladly accept any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you asked for.
You can use **Ajax** to make the php request and get the result as a javascript variable.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax(function(){
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'url_of_file.php',
     data: { 'var': var_for_query }, // type and data are not necessary if you don't need to send js variables through php
     success: function(data){
       function updateChart() {
         // ...
       }
     }
  });
</script>
```

**'data'** is just the result of your php script so basically just print the result, like

```
$array = array($row['something'],etc...);
echo $array;
```

**Disclaimer:** But for update the content you have to make the sql request every time if the rows are changed, just putting the code inside a function that you call whenever you want to update the page.

Comment: I have tried this but now the graph just stoped working and won't even display the data that was already imported from the database. I am unsure why this would break the rest of the program. As a last try here is my whole [code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14zhPViv3wguuYMSKvN7jF9F2S2ktZfEk?usp=sharing) I know this is asking a lot but I would like if you would check it out. If not then thank you for your time.

Comment: @HenriqueLopes what are the values you need to “transfer” from the php file to the js script?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @mignaway the values I want to transfer from my database are Hum and Temp.

Comment: @HenriqueLopes and where are these variables on your js script? I mean, you should change your graph based on your variables on your db right?